# How function snd in Haskell works in filter

Tags: list, haskell, filter, filtering, predicate

I type this code to ghci

```
Prelude> filter snd [('a',True),('b',True),('c',False),('d',True)]
```

why it returns

```
[('a',True),('b',True),('d',True)]
```

rather than

```
[('a',True),('c',False),('d',True)]
```

`snd` function returns the second item, so why not `filter snd` filter the second item?

Comment: Can you please explain why you expect that outcome? I can't grasp the logic which you expect `filter snd` to use.

Comment: @RobinZigmond: I think Jesse thinks that it means "filtering out every second element" as in one retaining, one removing, one retaining, ...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no, just the second one *in a list*. they've added an example.

Comment: here in *this* use case, `snd` is the same as `(\ x -> snd x == True)` is the same as `(\ (_,b) -> b == True)`, which might be clearer for you. but of course just `snd` (which is the same as `(\ (_,b) -> b)`) is the preferred spelling. the implied `(== True)` is part of the `filter` semantics, i.e. it is how the `filter` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In short**: `filter snd` retains 2-tuples where the second item of the tuple is `True`.

[**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) takes as parameter a function that maps elements of type `a` to a `Bool`. In case the `Bool` is `True` it will retain the element of the original list in the result, otherwise that element will not be part of the result.

`filter` thus filters *elementwise*: it does *not* take into account the next or previous element(s) in the list. It simply checks if a predicate on an element is satisfied.

Since you here have a list of 2-tuples where the second item of each tuple is a `Bool`, the [**`snd :: (a, b) -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:snd) will thus map each element on the second element, and thus retain 2-tuples where the second item of the 2-tuple is `True`. The most generic type of `filter snd` is thus `filter snd :: [(a, Bool)] -> [(a, Bool)]`, since the second item of the 2-tuples should be a `Bool`.

This thus means that `filter snd` indeed will filter like:

```
Prelude> filter snd [('a',True),('b',True),('c',False),('d',True)]
[('a',True),('b',True),('d',True)]
```

We can filter out every second element with explicit recursion for example:

```
filterAtEven :: [a] -> [a]
filterAtEven [] = []
filterAtEven (x:xs) = x : filterAtOdd xs

filterAtOdd :: [a] -> [a]
filterAtOdd [] = []
filterAtOdd (_:xs) = filterAtEven xs
```

for example:

```
Prelude> filterAtEven [('a',True),('b',True),('c',False),('d',True)]
[('a',True),('c',False)]
Prelude> filterAtOdd [('a',True),('b',True),('c',False),('d',True)]
[('b',True),('d',True)]
```

Or if you want to remove a specific index, we can make use of [**`deleteAt :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ilist-0.3.1.0/docs/Data-List-Index.html#v:deleteAt) of the [**`ilist`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ilist-0.3.1.0) package:

```
Prelude> import Data.List.Index
Prelude Data.List.Index> deleteAt 2 [('a',True),('b',True),('c',False),('d',True)]
[('a',True),('b',True),('d',True)]
```

or we can implement this ourselves:

```
deleteAt :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
deleteAt i | i < 0 = id
           | otherwise = go i
  where go _ [] = []
        go 0 (_:xs) = xs
        go n (x:xs) = x : go (n-1) xs
```

Answer (score 9):

You expect `filter` to "filter out" elements from a list in the [colloquial sense](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/filter-out) of that expression, and thus `filter snd`  to remove the second item.

That is not how it works

If you were right, `filter snd [1,2,3]` would evaluate to `[1,3]`. Instead, it doesn't typecheck, as `snd` works on tuples, not on numbers.

So, how does it work?

`filter f [item1, item2, ...]` returns a list of all `item`s for which `f item` is `True`

For example, `filter even [1,2,3,4]` returns `[2,4]`

As `snd ('b', True)` evaluates to `True`, in your example `filter` will include `(b, True)` in the result. By the same token, `(c, False)` will be omitted

Answer (score 4):

Your `filter` function filters your list according to the second value of each pair. This is why `('c',False)` is filtered out ...

Comment: so it filter second value, why return ['a','b','c','d']? I mean, it filter all second of each pair.

Comment: @Jesse: no `filter snd` on a list of elements that are no 2-tuples, or 2-tuples without the second item being a `Bool` makes no sense.